# How to make previous version live for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I found the backup version, how can I make it the live version?  I see in the screenshot of the [Chrome folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN866.jpg) that the files are there but how can I make the previous version the live version?  Version 51 is causing slow downs and I have to roll users back.

Answer (score 0):

#### I have to roll users back

You cannot rollback Chrome.

> **Can I roll back Google Chrome to a previous version?**
>
> - No - rollback is not supported.
> - To get to a previous version (which would not be supported by Google), you would need to uninstall your current version, delete
>     every user's saved profile data, and re-install the older version. 
>     Users' personal profile data is kept in:
>
>   - On Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data`
>   - On Windows Vista / 7: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`
> - This means users will lose their bookmarks, history, etc., so use this method with extreme caution.

Source [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/frequently-asked-questions)